# I want to filter a search on code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to filter this search so that the names do not repeat when displaying

```
$this->db->get_where('patient', array('id' => $appointment->patient))->row()->name;
```

Comment: You have to use GROUP_BY clause to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, in search need to add user name.

$this->db->select('name')->from('table')
       ->where("column LIKE '%$keyword%'")->get()->result_array();